# How to trim charcters from beginning and end of string with regex?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to remove `\r\n` and '\n' from text. The problem is that sometimes they are necessary. E.g.:

```
\r\n \nTitle\r\nText on the next row\r\n\r\nSignature\r\n
```

The ones between the text should be kept. Expected output:

```
Title\r\nText on the next row\r\n\r\nSignature
```

The '\r\n' and '\n' and ' ' from the start of the string are gone, as well as '\r\n' from the end of it. The rest are kept. I've tried various things similar to this

```
var reg = new Regex(@"(^(\r\n)+?)");
```

but can't get it to work properly.

Comment: Why is Regex a stipulation? String.Trim accepts a list of chars to trim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just

```
yourString.Trim()
```

it..

Or some variation on the overload that takes the chars if you ever want other than whitespace(or if you specifically want just those whitespace):

```
yourString.Trim("\r \n".ToCharArray()); //maybe store this ToCharArray call elsewhere as a fixed set of delimiters 
yourString.Trim(new[]{'\r','\n',' '}); //consider store elsewhere
yourString.Trim('\r','\n',' ');
```

If it really has to be regex, you can capture all the interesting part:

```
Regex.Match("^[\r\n ]*(?<x>.?*)[\r\n ]*$").Groups["x"].Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string.Trim()` with multiple characters

```cs
var text = "\r\n \nTitle\r\nText on the next row\r\n\r\nSignature\r\n";

text = text.Trim('\r', '\n');
```